# lost photos on iphone5

Tags: iphone, photos

Had a problem with iphone 5 so took phone to Apple rep proceeded to put my phone in restore thinking my photos were all in icloud....well no majority were in camera roll and didnot make it upon the restore.
So can I get these photos back or are they gone for ever?

Answer (score 1):

If you had Photo Stream enabled, as many as the most recent thousand will be available on there. Unfortunately, without a backup to iTunes or import from another app, they will no longer be on the device in an accessible way. I'm surprised the Genius who helped you didn't stress this point more emphatically.